# What is the point of Lodash's `_.ary` function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

What is the point of Lodash's [`_.ary` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#ary)? The example given is...

```js
_.map(['6', '8', '10'], _.ary(parseInt, 1));
```

... and I can see that this is helpful because `map` calls the callback function with three arguments, `value`, `index`, and `collection`, and `parseInt` on its own would misinterpret the `index` as the `radix`, giving this wrong result:

```js
[6, NaN, 2]
```

However, wouldn't it be simpler to just write...

```js
['6', '8', '10'].map(x => parseInt(x))
```

... without using Lodash?

Comment: I think this is a good question, but honestly the choice between a purpose-written wrapper function or using the library is a matter of style and not objectively answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly write your own function as a callback to `.map()`, but what `.ary()` gives you is the ability to forcibly ignore the additional parameters the runtime passes to things like the `.map()` callback. Without `.ary()`, the runtime passes 3 parameters to `.map()`, and that can cause problems with using some common methods as callbacks. The `_.ary()` method "undoes" that behavior, invoking the wrappered function with only as many parameters as you ask for.

The `parseInt()` function is a good example because it can be passed a second parameter to specify the numeric base desired for parsing the string. Because `.map()` passes the index into the iterated array as the second parameter, that would make `parseInt()` confused and almost certainly not give the right result.

Comment: I will admit that in my personal opinion, with modern JavaScript there's not much point to Lodash in general. It was super valuable when first introduced, but modern runtimes have many of the same features and they're likely to be much more highly optimized.

Comment: Then again I still like jQuery, so perhaps the truth is in the middle.